# Grasshopper jumps

Tags: elementary-number-theory, continuity, approximation-theory

A grasshopper has two legs, with one leg it can jump for `a`, and the other for `b`, in any direction on the number line. The numbers `a` and `b` are real numbers.

What points can a grasshopper hit on a straight line?

Comment: You tagged this with approximation theory. Are you just interested in getting “close” to any point? Or exactly on any given point?

Comment: Clearly you can only reach countably many points in this manner, so no.

Comment: Please edit your post for clarity and to indicate your efforts.  As stated, the answer is clearly no, but perhaps you meant something else. Perhaps, say, you would be ok with achieving a dense set of points on the line (you tag "continuity" and "approximation-theory" after all).  That is certainly doable.  But it's hard to guess what you wanted from your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of the jumps does not matter: we can jump $a,b,-a,-b$, so we can get any number of the form $\lambda a+\mu b$ for $\lambda,\mu\in\mathbb{Z}$, and no other numbers.

In particular, note that this is a countably infinite number of numbers (infinite because we can choose $\lambda=1,2,3,\dots$ and countable because we can describe each number by a finite description of one set of jumps the grasshopper can take to get there). The real numbers are uncountably infinite, so almost all numbers cannot be reached in this way.